# AWK: partial match from one file in another file with a special format on different columns

Tags: awk

A sample of my TSV `file1` (which has more extra columns but for the sake of simplicity is reduced) where the columns of interests are `CHROM` and `POS`:

```
CHROM   POS         REF     ALT     QUAL    MoreColumns
chr11   8823729     G       C       605.77  ...
chr1    16619       C       T       95.77   ...
chr1    16949       A       C       559.77  ...
chr1    17005       A       G       172.77  ...
chr1    17020       G       A       345.77  ...
chr12   8822661     G       A       880.77  ...
chr1    17697       G       C       412.77  ...
chr14   8837474     T       C       411.77  ...
chr1    129285      G       A       2509.77 ...
```

A sample of my TSV `file2` where the column of interest is `Extra_information` and has the following format:

```
Column1 ... Column9     Extra_information                                                       Column11
data    ... longline    hg38:Chr12:8822661, hg19:Chr12:8975257, COM:morewords, dbSNP:link       No
data2   ... longline2   hg38:Chr11:8823729, hg19:chr12:8976325, COM:morewords2, dbSNP:link2     No
data3   ... longline3   hg38:chr12:8823762, hg19:Chr12:8976358, COM:morewords3                  Yes
data4   ... longline4   hg38:chr12:8835642, hg19:Chr12:8988238, dbSNP:link3                     No
data5   ... longline5   hg38:Chr14:8837474, hg19:chr12:8990070, dbSNP:link4                     Yes
data6   ... longline6   hg19:Chr12:8990937, COM:morewords4, dbSNP:link5                         No
data7   ... longline7   hg38:chr12:8839209, PC:someinfo                                         No
```

My problem:

I want to perform a partial match of `hg38:CHROM:POS` from `file1` to `Extra_information` from `file2` and print the line of `file1` + `"\t" 1` if partial match is true else line of `file1` + `"\t" 0`. `Chr` can also be `chr` in `Extra_information` from `file2`.

My desired first output

```
CHROM   POS         REF     ALT     QUAL    MoreColumns     Match
chr11   8823729     G       C       605.77  ...             1
chr1    16619       C       T       95.77   ...             0
chr1    16949       A       C       559.77  ...             0
chr1    17005       A       G       172.77  ...             0
chr1    17020       G       A       345.77  ...             0
chr12   8822661     G       A       880.77  ...             1
chr1    17697       G       C       412.77  ...             0
chr14   8837474     T       C       411.77  ...             1
chr1    129285      G       A       2509.77 ...             0
```

My preferred second output

```
CHROM   POS         REF     ALT     QUAL    MoreColumns     Column1 ... Column9     Extra_information                                                       Column11
chr11   8823729     G       C       605.77  ...             data2   ... longline2   hg38:Chr11:8823729, hg19:chr12:8976325, COM:morewords2, dbSNP:link2     No
chr1    16619       C       T       95.77   ...             -       ... -               -                                                                   -
chr1    16949       A       C       559.77  ...             -       ... -               -                                                                   -
chr1    17005       A       G       172.77  ...             -       ... -               -                                                                   -
chr1    17020       G       A       345.77  ...             -       ... -               -                                                                   -
chr12   8822661     G       A       880.77  ...             data    ... longline    hg38:Chr12:8822661, hg19:Chr12:8975257, COM:morewords, dbSNP:link       No
chr1    17697       G       C       412.77  ...             -       ... -               -                                                                   -
chr14   8837474     T       C       411.77  ...             data5   ... longline5   hg38:Chr14:8837474, hg19:chr12:8990070, dbSNP:link4                     Yes
chr1    129285      G       A       2509.77 ...             -       ... -               -                                                                   -
```

I tried:

```sh
awk -F $'\t' 'NR == FNR 
    { a=("hg38:"file1[$1]":"file1[$2]); a=$NF; next } 
    { if ($10~$NF) {
       print file1[$0] "\t1"
    } else { 
       print file1[$0] "\t0"
    }
}' file1 file2
```

How can I achieve the desired output (preferably the second one) using `awk` ? (or if you could propose any other bash solution)

Thank you in advance.

Note: I have ~70k lines from `file1` to perform a partial match to `file2` which contains ~160k lines.

## Edit:

As requested by @Hai Vu for a complete line:

`File1`:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kB4i7bpbA6zV1kRvGB3cBvt5RWYSurVJ

and `File2`:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gZ6qkYRuyEVT4Txom0sAawT2-F81reQN

Comment: It is usually best in cases like this to use the tools Unix provides. For instance, in this case Unix provides a join command that performs the needed join. Use an awk preprocessor to convert your file to the format required by join, run join, then use an awk postprocessor to produce the final output. The two awk programs will be simple; the complexity is in the join, which Unix provides for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to solve it. I created an AWK script and called it *hg38.awk*. To invoke it:

```
awk -f hg38.awk file2 file1
```

Note that I scan file2 before file1. Here is the script:

```
# In file2 where we found hg38
# We transform "hg38:Chr11:8823729," to "chr11:8823729"
# And use that as a key in the array `found`
NR == FNR && $4 ~ /^hg38:/ {
    extra = $4
    sub(/hg38:/, "", extra)
    sub(/Chr/, "chr", extra)
    sub(/,$/, "", extra)
    found[extra] = 1
}

# First line of file1
# Print the existing headers and an additional column
NR != FNR && FNR == 1 {
    print $0 "\tMatch"
    next
}

# Subsequent lines of file1
NR != FNR {
    printf $0
    key = $1 ":" $2
    if (key in found) {
        print "\t1"
    } else {
        print "\t0"
    }
}
```

## Explanations

- In the script, I scan file2 first (see the command line). To distinguish between the two files, I look at the relationship between `NR` and `FNR` variables. If they are the same, I am scanning the first file on the command line (hence, file2). If they differ, I am working on file1.
- For the first and second blocks of code, I hope the comments will be adequate
- In the last block, I constructed the key from the fields, e.g. "chr11:8823729" and check to see if that key is in the array `found` and output accordingly.

## Update

Here I modified the script to output your second desired output. The changes invole in storing the entire row of file2 and the construction of an empty row.

```
NR == FNR && FNR == 1 {
    headers = $0
    empty_row = ""
    for (i = 0; i < NF; i++) {
        empty_row = "\t-" empty_row
    }
    next
}

# In file2 where we found hg38
# We transform "hg38:Chr11:8823729," to "chr11:8823729"
# And use that as a key in the array `found`
NR == FNR && $4 ~ /^hg38:/ {
    extra = $4
    sub(/hg38:/, "", extra)
    sub(/Chr/, "chr", extra)
    sub(/,$/, "", extra)
    found[extra] = $0
}

# First line of file1
# Print the existing headers and an additional column
NR != FNR && FNR == 1 {
    print $0 "\t" headers
    next
}

# Subsequent lines of file1
NR != FNR {
    printf $0
    key = $1 ":" $2
    if (key in found) {
        print "\t" found[key]
    } else {
        print empty_row
    }
}
```

## Update 2

With the latest data from Google, I discovered what file2.tsv, field 10 is more complex than I thought. With that, I was able to work out the version 3 of my solution:

```
# Works with TSV  (tab-separated values) file
BEGIN {
    FS = "\t"
}

# In file2.tsv, save the headers and create a row of empty data (just dashes)
NR == FNR && FNR == 1 {
    headers = $0
    empty_row = ""
    for (i = 0; i < NF; i++) {
        empty_row = "\t-" empty_row
    }
    next
}

# In file2.tsv where we found hg38
# We transform "hg38:Chr11:8823729," to "chr11:8823729"
# And use that as a key in the array `found`
NR == FNR && $10 ~ /^hg38:/ {
    extra = $10
    sub(/hg38:/, "", extra)
    sub(/Chr/, "chr", extra)
    sub(/,.*$/, "", extra)
    found[extra] = $0
}

# First line of file1
# Print the existing headers and additional columns
NR != FNR && FNR == 1 {
    print $0 "\t" headers
    next
}

# Subsequent lines of file1
NR != FNR {
    printf $0
    key = $1 ":" $2
    if (key in found) {
        print "\t" found[key]
    } else {
        print empty_row
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposed answer and the explanation ! For the first block, I changed the `$4` to `$10` since my `Extra_information` is on the 10th column. I tried your script but it still printed `-` for the matching `key`.

Comment: How about providing the complete lines from file1 and file2, just select a few rows and replaced sensitive data with something else like "XXX"

Comment: You could replace the multiple spaces by tabs

Comment: @Zen, some cells in your file has spaces. That means converting spaces to tab will cause misaligned of data. Can you convert your file TSV and upload somewhere? Or convert them to comma-separated values (CSV) files?

Comment: I edited my post to add links for downloading the two files with TSV format. I can't change to CSV since there are already comma in the `Extra_information` column of `file2`

Comment: Thanks a lot for th e help @Hai Vu ! it is very fast too ! I would like to suggest only a small change to your code in the last block where you type `printf $0` to `printf "%s", $0" since if there are any special characters like `%20` in URL links, it won't cause any problem

Comment: That is great. Go ahead and implement your change. Good luck.